# I install bs4, but then get "No module named 'bs4'"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

UPDATE: Thank you to everyone who answered and commented. I understand now that I have 2 versions of python installed.  My program was running from "Miniconda3/python.exe ".  While bs4 was installed in "c:\python38\lib\site-packages".  I understand this to be the cause of the problem.  I removed Minicoda3 but VS code still tries to use it when I run a program.  How can I fix this?

When I run the following code:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Error:

```
I get the error: "No module named 'bs4'. 
After I install bs4, It says "Requirement already satisfied" yet I get the same error.
```

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong, please help. Error messages below.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\exAPP> pip install bs4
Collecting bs4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.0.1)     
Using legacy setup.py install for bs4, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: bs4
Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\exAPP> & C:/Users/Admin/Miniconda3/python.exe c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JNB.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JNB.py", line 2, in <module>
    import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\exAPP> & C:/Users/Admin/Miniconda3/python.exe c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JNB.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JNB.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\exAPP>
```

Comment: Always invoke `pip` as `python -m pip install ...`. Could you try `python -m pip install bs4` and then `python /path/to/file.py` ?

Comment: you have different versions of python installed

Answer (score 0):

You are using `miniconda`, which might not be on your PATH correctly such that `pip` is actually part of a separate Python installation.

You could use `conda install pip`, or `C:/Users/Admin/Miniconda3/python.exe -m pip install bs4`

Comment: I tried "conda install pip" and got "conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Like I said, your PATH is misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my problems are fixed an my program is running.  Like I said in the update the first problem was due to having 2 versions of python installed.  After I removed the unwanted version it was still set as the python interpreter path.  I was trying to fix this by going into VS code settings but was having no luck.  Fortunately I finally noticed there was a button on bottom left of the screen that allowed me to change the path easily.  Thanks again to those who commented and answered.